# Protecting url / link from copy & paste/sharing

Tags: url, sharing, copy, mask, hide

I would like to know whether it is possible to do the following:

I have a link that is generated by a software package and this link is then used as a hyperlink / url input on an app via an icon. I don't have access to the source code of the app nor can I access the link-generating software. The issue I face is that if unauthoried people get the url and punch it into a browser address bar, they will then have access to the information that is being fed from that url. How can I prevent this from taking place....I have read that it is a security risk to hide or block out the address bar. The only access I have is that I can type in the url address into the app update fields for the icons, so if there's a method to add comments or code to the the url, eg color background and foreground, write-protect, etc, that would help solve my issue. The URL links are not public files. These point to a server that hosts my information, eg. an audio feed from a seminar or a live feed from a business talk.

URL Link example: https://player.hostname/0000/stream